# How to add some text in the default slider in opencart 2.x?

Tags: opencart

I am using Opencart 2.1. How can I add some text on the default slider provided by Opencart ? I want the font to be formatted and the position of the text can be changed.

Please help.

Comment: Which opencart slider?

Comment: It is "Slideshow" module given by default with OpenCart version 2.1.0.1

Comment: There is title field in index.php?route=design/banner/edit  this page of admin use this for your text

Answer (score 0):

Use `nivoslider` opencart module. It gives you much more flexibility to add text along with it's position.

In default slider, you can add text via `Banner title`.